# Regular expression to capture groups delimited by an expression

Tags: python, r, regex

How to capture `[0-9]+` groups delimited by `(\], \[)`? For example, in the case of

```
[[[[u'1', u'2'], u'3'], u'4'], [[[u'1', u'2'], u'4'], [[u'1', u'5'], u'4']]]
```

I would like to capture three groups, `1 2 3 4`, `1 2 4` and `1 5 4`.

Comment: You should be using a parser for this, not a regex.  Regex doesn't handle nested structure well.

Comment: Thank you, @TimBiegeleisen! I spent too long time trying to flatten the list and then hoped to find a magical regex that solves everything but your comment opened my eyes and solved it with a combination of a re.split and re.findall in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you don't have sub-patterns like `[[u'1', u'2'], [u'3',u'5']]` (multiple nested sub-groups at the same level, in which case you need to use a stack and parse like pushdown automata) you could do this with regular expressions in two steps:

(1) split the expression with regex `\]\s*,\s*\[` to get the groups first, you will get 3 groups for the example provided.

(2) within each group use the regex `[^0-9u]*u'([0-9]+)'[^0-9u]*` to extract the digits.

For example, in `R`, the code will be:

```
str <- "[[[[u'1', u'2'], u'3'], u'4'], [[[u'1', u'2'], u'4'], [[u'1', u'5'], u'4']]]"
groups <- unlist(strsplit(str, split='\\]\\s*,\\s*\\['))
pattern <- "[^0-9u]*u'([0-9]+)'[^0-9u]*"
lapply(groups, function(str) gsub(pattern, "\\1", regmatches(str,gregexpr(pattern,str))[[1]]))

#[[1]]
#[1] "1" "2" "3" "4"

#[[2]]
#[1] "1" "2" "4"

#[[3]]
#[1] "1" "5" "4"
```

In `python`:

```
import re
str = "[[[[u'1', u'2'], u'3'], u'4'], [[[u'1', u'2'], u'4'], [[u'1', u'5'], u'4']]]"
groups = re.split('\]\s*,\s*\[', str)
pattern = "[^0-9u]*u'([0-9]+)'[^0-9u]*"
print map(lambda x: re.findall(pattern, x), groups)
# [['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['1', '2', '4'], ['1', '5', '4']]
```

you could map the digits to integers if required.